# How to get data values and store in variables in flutter from json model class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am a new in flutter but I have a good knowledge of java.

My Model Class

```
  UserDashboard({
    required this.joinedUpcomingClasses,
  });
  late final List<JoinedUpcomingClasses> joinedUpcomingClasses;



  UserDashboard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    joinedUpcomingClasses = List.from(json['joinedUpcomingClasses']).map((e)=>JoinedUpcomingClasses.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['joinedUpcomingClasses'] = joinedUpcomingClasses.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class JoinedUpcomingClasses {
  JoinedUpcomingClasses({
    required this.id,
    required this.classes,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final Classes classes;

  JoinedUpcomingClasses.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    classes = Classes.fromJson(json['classes']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['classes'] = classes.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Classes {
  Classes({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.location,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String location;

  Classes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    location = json['location'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['location'] = location;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

I just want to get the Class name and location in my future builder.
In java, we used simply getter
Java example                     userDashboard.getjoinedUpcomingClasses().getclasses().getname(),

but in dart how can I get the values of the name and location of the class?

Comment: could add your response code too? and where do you want to get this ? in result of api call?

Comment: My Json
{
  "joinedUpcomingClasses": [
    {
      "id": 62,
      "classes": {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "learn java",
        "location": "Noida sector 60 block A",
        
      },
      
    }
  ],
  
}

Comment: i just want to get value of classes name and location for set in text widget in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want get these data from api response, try this:

```
UserDashboard result = UserDashboard.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

and then use it like this:

```
Text(result.joinedUpcomingClasses[0].classes.name);
```

Comment: I already did this but now how to print a particular class name